# Can someone please explain me how this came?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, differentiation, vector-fields, calculus

[image]

I am not getting how above equation is derived using cylindrical coordinates transformations.

This is from page 36, Mathew Sadiku

Comment: Scans of text and math are not appropriate on this site. They aren’t searchable and they aren’t accessible by visually impaired members. You are expected to type the text and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation (2.17) is using the [chain rule for partial derivatives](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~jdg/AECHAIN.PDF).

Comment: Yes, I though of that but if I apply chain rule I must get rho in numerator rather than in denominator

Comment: Thank you, it worked